# How to convert combined data set to dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

This is my input list:

```
input_data = ['ned','etainclub','codingart','codingman','ksc','imrahelk', 'newbijohn','coinfarmer165','ponzipanda','blockchainstudio','jisoooh0202', 'jamieinthedark','xinnong','bbooaae','onehand','osyvv','bluengel','jungjunghoon','duplicate','lucky2']
```

I have defined function `predict` and after calling this function on the data I get this result:

```
[{'ned': 'male'}, {'etainclub': 'male'}, {'codingart': 'male'}, {'codingman': 'male'}, {'ksc': 'male'}, {'imrahelk': 'male'}, {'newbijohn': 'male'}, {'coinfarmer165': 'male'}, {'ponzipanda': 'female'}, {'blockchainstudio': 'male'}, {'jisoooh0202': 'male'}, {'jamieinthedark': 'male'}, {'xinnong': 'male'}, {'bbooaae': 'female'}, {'onehand': 'male'}, {'osyvv': 'male'}, {'bluengel': 'male'}, {'jungjunghoon': 'male'}, {'duplicate': 'female'}, {'lucky2': 'male'}]
```

This table below is the target format I want to get from the above data:

| name | gender |
| --- | --- |
| ned | male |
| etainclub | male |
| duplicate | female |
| lucky2 | male |

Comment: Hi Junoy, welcome to StackOverflow!

Can you please reformat the code in the question using the code formatter in the text editor?

Comment: @ebeb9, I updated. Is is ok?

Answer (score 0):

The `predict_output` is a list of dicts. You can first convert it to a list of lists by getting the items of each dict element then pass the result to `spark.createDataFrame()`:

```
import itertools

data = itertools.chain(*[p.items() for p in predict_output])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "gender"])
df.show(5)

#+---------+------+
#|     name|gender|
#+---------+------+
#|      ned|  male|
#|etainclub|  male|
#|codingart|  male|
#|codingman|  male|
#|      ksc|  male|
#+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution without using itertools:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[k,v] for i in predict_output for k,v in i.items()],
    ['name', 'gender']
)
```